# asp.net oauth build in facebook authentication

Tags: asp.net, facebook, authentication, oauth

how to finish off logging in with facebook account (and keep those details in membership db). I was reading around that one needs to get user's email, of course adding any email or name in txt box will not validate ... however it is possible to add it as another service after user logged in with any other method like google or so...

so how do i change the code to get user's email pulled from fb whilst using built in oauth model in .net 4.5